# Trying to run through a list of keywords against many text files and output slice of text to csv in Python

Tags: python, csv, text-extraction, text-search

I'm a Python noob.

I am trying to read a list of keywords in a text file, open and read many text files to search for the keyword list, extract a text slice for each instance of each keyword, and then output all text slices to a csv file.

I have the code below, but when I run it, it only searches the first keyword against the first file, writes to csv, and closes. I have searched for an answer, but haven't quite found what I'm looking for.

Any ideas on where I messed this up?

```
import os
import re

def formatText(s):
    s = s.replace("[", "")
    s = s.replace("]", "")
    s = s.replace(",", "")
    s = s.replace("[", "")
    s = s.replace("\n", " ")
    s = s.replace("\r", " ")
    return s

fdoc = wlitems = None
termct = None

f = open(r'filenames.txt')
fdoc = f.read()
flist = fdoc.split('\n')
if f: f.close()

wlist = open(r'keywords.txt')
try:
    wltxt = wlist.read()
    wlitems = wltxt.split('\n')
finally:
    if wlist: wlist.close()

if wlitems and fdoc:
    op = open(r'output.csv', 'w')
    try:
        termct = {}
        for chnk in flist:
            if not chnk == "":
                chnknum = flist.index(chnk)
                curfile = open(chnk)
                curfilecnts = curfile.read()
                ucurfilecnts = curfilecnts.upper()
                filelength = len(ucurfilecnts)
                for kwrd in wlitems:
                    if len(kwrd)>0:
                        curpos = 0
#                   print keyword
                        keyd = re.compile(kwrd,re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
                        while curpos <= filelength:
                            sumline = keyd.search(ucurfilecnts,curpos)
#                   print sumline
                            if sumline:
                                curpos = sumline.end()
                                keydtxt = curfilecnts[sumline.start()-20: sumline.end()+200]
                                op.write(chnk + "," + kwrd + "," + str(curpos) + "," + formatText(keydtxt) + "\n")
                            else:
                                curpose = filelength +1
    finally:
            if op: op.close()
```

Comment: could you narrow down your problem to a smaller chunk of code? also I'd recommend using `''.translate()` for your formatText function

Comment: It doesn't look to me like it processes any files listed in `filenames.txt`. To do that, you'll need to add a loop after opening `output.csv` that opens, reads, and processes the data in each filename in `flist` while writing the results of searching for keywords to the output file.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Got it figured out.